# Difference between various types of FSM coding style

Tags: system-verilog, fsm

I'm designing a coin change counter using Moore FSM. The target is to convert the input value to the numbers of coins of value one, five, ten composing the equivalent value. To my understanding so far, Moore FSM is composed of three parts:

1. State register(sequential)
2. Next state logic(sequential or combinational?)
3. Output logic(sequential or combinational?)

And there are several types of FSM coding styles grouping the above segments in single always block. I've shown two kinds of versions below, one grouping state register + next state logic, the other having separated three always blocks.

So I'm wondering that:

1. Must the next state logic or output logic written in sequential or combinational logic?
2. What are the differences between those coding styles besides number of flip-flops synthesized?
3. Are those styles all interchangeable or only some are feasible under certain circumstances?
4. What are the pros and cons using those coding styles?

Any help will be appreciated! Thx:)

Combining state register + next state logic:

```
//--------------------------------------//
//           MODULE DECLARATION         //
//--------------------------------------//

module coin(
    // input signals
    clk,
    rst_n,
    in_coin,
    in_valid,

    // output signals
    out_valid,
    out_ten_coin,
    out_five_coin,
    out_one_coin
);

//--------------------------------------//
//           PORT DECLARATION           //
//--------------------------------------//

    input clk;
    input rst_n;
    input [5:0]in_coin;
    input in_valid;

    // Because output coin numbers and out_valid are only 
    // high for one cycle, so don't need to store in registers 
    // and are manipulated in always_comb!
    output logic out_valid;
    output logic [2:0]out_ten_coin;
    output logic [2:0]out_five_coin;
    output logic [2:0]out_one_coin;

    // Combining State Register and Next State Logic, 
    // so don't need "next_state" register!
    logic [2:0]state;
    // logic [2:0]next_state;

    // Because input coin value last for only one cycle,
    // need to be stored in register for usage later!
    logic [5:0]in_coin_reg;

    // Because number of coins change every cycle and need to 
    // output at last cycle, need to be stored in registers and
    // manipulated in always_ff block!
    logic [2:0]out_one_coin_reg;
    logic [2:0]out_five_coin_reg;
    logic [2:0]out_ten_coin_reg;
    
//--------------------------------------//
//         PARAMETER DECLARATION        //
//--------------------------------------//

    parameter IDLE  = 3'b000;
    parameter CHECK = 3'b001;
    parameter ONE   = 3'b010;
    parameter FIVE  = 3'b011;
    parameter TEN   = 3'b100;
    parameter OUT   = 3'b101;

//--------------------------------------//
//            CIRCUIT DESIGN            //
//--------------------------------------//

    /// Uses Moore machine to design FSM

    // Combining State Register and Next State Logic
    // State Register
    always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if (!rst_n) begin
            state <= IDLE;
        end
        else begin
            // Next state logic
            case(state)
                IDLE: begin
                    if (in_valid) begin
                        state  <= CHECK;
                        in_coin_reg <= in_coin;
                    end
                    else begin
                        state <= IDLE;
                    end
                    out_one_coin_reg  <= 0;
                    out_five_coin_reg <= 0;
                    out_ten_coin_reg  <= 0;
                end
                CHECK: begin
                    if (in_coin_reg >= 10) begin
                        state <= TEN;
                    end
                    else if (in_coin_reg < 10 && in_coin_reg >= 5) begin
                        state <= FIVE;
                    end
                    else if (in_coin_reg < 5 && in_coin_reg >= 1) begin
                        state <= ONE;
                    end
                    else begin
                        state <= OUT;
                    end
                end
                ONE: begin
                    in_coin_reg  <= in_coin_reg - 1;
                    out_one_coin_reg <= out_one_coin_reg + 1;
                    // out_one_coin <= out_one_coin + 1;
                    state <= CHECK;
                end
                FIVE: begin
                    in_coin_reg   <= in_coin_reg - 5;
                    out_five_coin_reg <= out_five_coin_reg + 1;
                    // out_five_coin <= out_five_coin + 1;
                    state <= CHECK;
                end
                TEN: begin
                    in_coin_reg  <= in_coin_reg - 10;
                    out_ten_coin_reg <= out_ten_coin_reg + 1;
                    // out_ten_coin <= out_ten_coin + 1;
                    state <= CHECK;
                end
                OUT: begin
                    // out_valid  <= 1;
                    state <= IDLE;
                end
        endcase
        end
    end

    // Output logic block
    always_comb begin   
        case (state)
            OUT: begin
                out_valid     = 1;
                out_one_coin  = out_one_coin_reg;
                out_five_coin = out_five_coin_reg;
                out_ten_coin  = out_ten_coin_reg;
            end
            default: begin
                out_valid     = 0;
                out_one_coin  = 0;
                out_five_coin = 0;
                out_ten_coin  = 0;
            end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

the output waveform:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YGrg.jpg)

And the separated three always blocks:

```
//--------------------------------------//
//           MODULE DECLARATION         //
//--------------------------------------//

module coin(
    // input signals
    clk,
    rst_n,
    in_coin,
    in_valid,

    // output signals
    out_valid,
    out_ten_coin,
    out_five_coin,
    out_one_coin
);

//--------------------------------------//
//           PORT DECLARATION           //
//--------------------------------------//

    input clk;
    input rst_n;
    input [5:0]in_coin;
    input in_valid;

    // Because output coin numbers and out_valid are only 
    // high for one cycle, so don't need to store in registers 
    // and are manipulated in always_comb!
    output logic out_valid;
    output logic [2:0]out_ten_coin;
    output logic [2:0]out_five_coin;
    output logic [2:0]out_one_coin;

    // Not combining State Register and Next 
    // State Logic, so need "next_state" register!
    logic [2:0]state;
    logic [2:0]next_state;

    // Because input coin value last for only one cycle,
    // need to be stored in register for usage later!
    logic [5:0]in_coin_reg;

    // Need this FF to avoid latches when using in_coin_reg in 
    // the next state logic!
    logic [5:0]in_coin_reg2;

    // Because number of coins change every cycle and need to 
    // output at last cycle, need to be stored in registers and
    // manipulated in always_ff block!
    logic [2:0]out_one_coin_reg;
    logic [2:0]out_five_coin_reg;
    logic [2:0]out_ten_coin_reg;
    
//--------------------------------------//
//         PARAMETER DECLARATION        //
//--------------------------------------//

    parameter IDLE  = 3'b000;
    parameter CHECK = 3'b001;
    parameter ONE   = 3'b010;
    parameter FIVE  = 3'b011;
    parameter TEN   = 3'b100;
    parameter OUT   = 3'b101;

//--------------------------------------//
//            CIRCUIT DESIGN            //
//--------------------------------------//

    /// Uses Moore machine to design FSM

    // State Register(Sequential block)
    always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if (!rst_n) begin
            state <= IDLE;
            in_coin_reg   <= 0;
            in_coin_reg2  <= 0;
            out_one_coin  <= 0;
            out_five_coin <= 0;
            out_ten_coin  <= 0;
        end 
        else if (in_valid) begin
            in_coin_reg <= in_coin;
            state       <= next_state;
        end
        else begin
            state <= next_state;
            in_coin_reg   <= in_coin_reg2;
            out_one_coin  <= out_one_coin_reg;
            out_five_coin <= out_five_coin_reg;
            out_ten_coin  <= out_ten_coin_reg;
        end
    end

    // Next state logic(Combinational block)
    always_comb begin
        in_coin_reg2 = in_coin_reg;
        out_one_coin_reg  = out_one_coin;
        out_five_coin_reg = out_five_coin;
        out_ten_coin_reg  = out_ten_coin;
        case(state)
                IDLE: begin
                    if (in_valid) begin
                        next_state  = CHECK;
                    end
                    else begin
                        next_state = IDLE;
                        out_one_coin_reg  = 0;
                        out_five_coin_reg = 0;
                        out_ten_coin_reg  = 0;
                    end
                end
                CHECK: begin
                    if (in_coin_reg2 >= 10) begin
                        next_state = TEN;
                    end
                    else if (in_coin_reg2 < 10 && in_coin_reg2 >= 5) begin
                        next_state = FIVE;
                    end
                    else if (in_coin_reg2 < 5 && in_coin_reg2 >= 1) begin
                        next_state = ONE;
                    end
                    else begin
                        next_state = OUT;
                    end
                end
                ONE: begin
                    in_coin_reg2 = in_coin_reg - 1;
                    out_one_coin_reg = out_one_coin + 1;
                    next_state = CHECK;
                end
                FIVE: begin
                    in_coin_reg2 = in_coin_reg - 5;
                    out_five_coin_reg = out_five_coin + 1;
                    next_state = CHECK;
                end
                TEN: begin
                    in_coin_reg2 = in_coin_reg - 10;
                    out_ten_coin_reg = out_ten_coin + 1;
                    next_state = CHECK;
                end
                OUT: begin
                    next_state = IDLE;
                end
        endcase 
    end

    // Output logic block(Combinational block)
    always_comb begin
        case (state)
            OUT: begin
                out_valid = 1;
            end
            default: begin
                out_valid = 0;
            end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

the output waveform:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFdI5.jpg)

### Updated:

In the three blocks case above, I have to use another variable in_coin_reg2 to avoid using
`in_coin_reg = in_coin_reg - 1;`
inside the always_comb which causes latches.
Seems like a wierd way to avoid latches, it works out though. Is there any better way?

Answer (score -1):

Historically, the FPGA synthesis tools were simply not very good. They could make mistakes when trying to synthesize state machines. People writing FPGA code came up with a recommended approach called the two always block (Verilog) or two process block (VHDL) approach. In this implementation, two always/process blocks are created. One controls the synchronous logic, in this case the current state register. The other controls the combination logic, in this case the next state determination.

There’s no functional difference between these two approaches, just stylistic differences. I’m not a big fan of the approach with two always/process blocks. Breaking up the LUT-based logic from the flip-flop based logic by using two separate blocks is confusing, especially for beginners. Compared to the single always/process block solution, it’s more complicated and less intuitive. It’s easy to make a mistake with this style.

The other reason that I avoid the two always/process block style is that I don’t like to use combinational always/process blocks if I can avoid them. The reason for this is that they can generate latches if you’re not careful. A latch can create unwanted behavior for your FPGA design and should be avoided. For those two reasons I recommend just keeping your state machine logic within a single process/always block. It’s easier to read and understand, and the tools are good enough now to build the state machine correctly.

Comment: You are correct about the style. It is all about ability of synthesis and different analysis tools to extract state machines. Readability is a vague concept. BTW, always_comb should take care of latches via compiler messages.

Comment: With next-state, and output logic in a single synchronous process, there is no way to have a combinational output based on a mealy style input.  There are circumstances where this would be desired, for example very high speed designs where pipelining everything is necessary.  For many designs this is not necessary, and it is valuable to be able to have a combinational output for protocols can't tolerate the extra clock of latency.

Comment: @Mikef Sure you could. Outside the always block do something like:
`assign my_out = (state == DATA_VALID) && i_DV;` You can also use ternary operator.

Comment: That could be considered another state machine style (which is fine) "one process + continuous assignments".

Comment: I find that the two always/process block style leaves open the possibility of combinatorial logic loops, while it is much harder to have a logic loop with a single synchronous process.